# Slot Game Average Win Calculation: Different Methods Give Different Results

Tags: probability

I'm trying to figure out why there is a difference between different methods of calculation of an average win for a slot game which consists of the base game and the bonus game (free spins that do not retrigger themselves). One of the methods was taken from "Elements Of Slot Design. 3rd Edition" (see the image below).

[image: Elements Of Slot Design. 3rd Edition]

Suppose, the average win of the base game is $ B_0 = 0.8~\$/spin $ and of the free spins game $ B_1 = 0.6~\$/spin $.

Let there be 100 combinations in the base game:

- 5 combinations trigger 5 free spins;
- 6 combinations trigger 10 free spins;
- 7 combinations trigger 15 free spins.

---

I calculated it in the following way.

Full round of the base game gives:

base game win:
$$ 100~spins \times 0.8~\$/spin = \$80 $$

and

free spins win:
$$ (5 + 10 + 15) \times 0.6 = 30~spins \times 0.6~\$/spin = \$18 $$

Thus, the final win is $ \$80 + \$18 = \$98 $. And the average win is:
$$ F = \$98 / 100~spins = 0.98~\$/spin $$

---

According to the book "Elements Of Slot Design. 3rd Edition":

The average number of free games:
$$ E(free games) = 5 / 100 \times 5 + 6 / 100 \times 10 + 7 / 100 \times 15 = 1.9 $$

The final average win is:
$$ F = 0.8~\$/spin + 1.9 \times 0.6~\$/spin = 1.94~\$/spin $$

---

**Question:** Where is the mistake(s)?

Comment: In your calculation you didn't use the fact that you get the free spins from 5, 6or 7 combinations (out of 100).

Comment: O, man! How stupid I am! I was looking for the source of the error all day long. Thank you very much!